Adding a `new line` symbol to a layer name in the QGIS layer table
Currently, you can copy and paste the text with a newline break and it will appear normally in the name of any layer in the QGIS layers window.
Is there any way to create a newline break using the keyboard (without copying and pasting it)?
For example, pressing (all this doesn't work):
Ctrl + Enter,
Alt + Enter,
Alt + 0 + 1 + 0  (in Windows) as commented by @she_weeds.


Hm, even ALT+010 in Windows doesn't work :(
